# NDC - SETID Mapping

Tags: openfda

I am interested in connecting the NDC data (brand_name, labeler etc.) to the FDA Label data (SET_ID). However, I'm struggling to find a dataset that would contain the mapping between the NDC code and the SET ID. Is there a crosswalk connecting the two?

Answer (score 0):

The openFDA NDC dataset will contain a SPL Set ID value in the `openfda.spl_set_id` element for most of the drugs. Here is a random example:

```
curl https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=packaging.package_ndc:57664-798-99 | grep -C 2 spl_set_id
```